# Classify data based on same type of data present is same array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array named **a** which contain number of words with certain characters . I want to classify it by it's name by removing # symbol. I think peoples may be unclear by my question so I have gave output of this program below.

My Array:-

```
var a = ['#name1#','#name2#','#name3#','#name1#','#name2#'];

function classify(a){
    var t = {};
    var y = [];
    a.forEach(function(f){
        var txt = f.replace('#','').trim();
        var txtnode = document.createTextNode(f);
        y.push(txtnode);
        t[txt] = y;
    })
   return t;
}

console.log(classify(a))
```

Output of this program that I want to obtain : -

```
{
  name1:(2) [text, text]
  name2:(2) [text, text]
  name3:(1) [text]
}
```

More information about given output :-

The given output may not be accurate because it is copied from console but this may give hints for programmer to solve this problem **name1** property of object contain 2 array which contain two textnodes having same type of data from same array they are **#name1#** in first textnode and *#name1#* in another textnode of property name likewise same in **name2** property of object contains **#name2#** in both textnodes in array similarly **name3** property of object contain only 1 textnode with data **#name3**

inside textnodes :-

```
 {
  name1:[#name1#,#name1#],
  name2:[#name2#,#name2#],
  name3:[#name3#]
}
```

**Please Don't use jquery**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are adding everything to a single array instead of creating a different array for each entry in the object.

Another problem with your code is that `f.replace('#', '')` only replaces the *first* instance of `#` in `f`.

This should have the desired behavior:

```js
function classify(a){
    var t = {};
    a.forEach(function(f){
        var txt = f.replace(/#/g,'').trim();
        var txtnode = document.createTextNode(f);
        
        t[txt] = (t[txt] || []).concat(txtnode);
    })
   return t;
}

var a = ['#name1#','#name2#','#name3#','#name1#','#name2#'];

var classified = classify(a);

console.log(classified.name1.length);
console.log(classified.name2.length);
console.log(classified.name3.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create an object from the array. On each iteration, get the key by removing the # signs.

If the key doesn't exist on the object, add it as a property with an empty array as value.

Push the current item to the relevant array.

```js
var a = ['#name1#','#name2#','#name3#','#name1#','#name2#'];

var result = a.reduce(function(r, s) {
  var key = s.replace(/#/g, '');
  
  r[key] || (r[key] = []);
  
  r[key].push(s); // document.createTextNode(s) instead of s in your actual code
  
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```